# find lists intersection in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo, nested-lists

I have a list of n lists and want to find their intersection, like:

```
[[1 2 3 4][0 4][4 1]]
[4]
```

I have found a code [here](http://www.turtlezero.com/models/view.php?model=set-intersection-tests) to find the intersection of two lists:

```
to-report intersect [a b]
   report (filter [ member? ? b ] a)
end
```

but I cannot figure out how I can extend this concept to multiple lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh! This is a very nice use case for NetLogo's under-appreciated [`reduce`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reduce) function.

Given your `intersect` reporter above:

```
print reduce intersect [[1 2 3 4][0 4][4 1]]
```

Will give you:

```
[4]
```

`reduce` applies `intersect` to the first and second sub-lists, and then it applies `intersect` to the result of that and the third sub-list, and so on for as many sub-lists as you have in your master list...